# Using a date range in an array formula

Tags: excel-formula

I've got a data-set, for example purposes it's a list of people (who may appear more than once) with various fields.

I need to return every match and I've done this with an array formula.

My data looks like this from Column A to F with the look up result shown in Column F. (I've simplified it for sample purposes):

[image: screenshot of data]

and the data updates perfectly when i update the name in cell F1

This is my formula

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$27, SMALL(IF(COUNTIF(F$1,$A$2:$A$27), ROW($C$2:$C$27)-1,""), ROW()-1)),"")}
```

However I need to also to include the **date** in the criteria, specifically I want to be able to **provide a date range**, and then only return matches that are within that date range.

I've found many examples of having multiple matches in the criteria (using more than 1 `countif` and multiplying the results together) but nothing that will allow me to specify a date range.

I don't want to use VBA for this, hoping someone out there can assist.

Answer (score 0):

always the case.
After posting that query, I managed to work it out myself.

I just changed my formula to :

{=IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$27, SMALL(IF(COUNTIF(F$1,$A$2:$A$27)*($G$1>=$B$2:$B$27), ROW($C$2:$C$27)-1,""), ROW()-1)),"")}

(where G1 had a date in it) i also added a <= statement in there as well to give it a start and end date

sorry for wasting the time of anyone who looked into this for me

Comment: I suggest you to either change the last bit `ROW()-1` to `ROW(2:2)-1` or specify this formula needs to be entered in the second row for it to function correctly.

Comment: thanks Terry, that's helpful!
I'd been changing the figure depending on where i put the formula